# Attach identifier to Scrapy request?

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy

I'm new to crawlers and networks in general, so this may be an ignorant question. I am trying to attach an identifier to each scrapy request so that I can identify each response.

As an example. Say I'm scraping the data from products I have stored in my database and I want to store the scraped data in the database associated with that particular product. Is there a way to attach an identifier to a request so that when the response returns I know what product it is referring to so that I can update the correct product in the database?

Based on the scraped data, I'm sure I could find identifiers on the page, but if I could pass an identifier with each request, it would be much easier and less error prone.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After reading the documentation further, I believe I found the answer [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-callback-arguments). I think I can use Requests [meta] attribute to pass additional information to the callbacks. I'm not entirely sure how this works via the example, but this is the best candidate that I've found so far.